# What will be best method to store this type of data in mongoDb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have to store this type of data in mongodb , for particular user there will be n number of customers whose details have to store. What will be best strategy to store. should I create collection for each user and store customer details in that collection. Suggest method to store and easy retreival.

```
{
  "user1": {
    "customer1": {
      "name": "name of customer",
      "ageGroup": "20-30",
      "localtion": "customer location",
      "email": "customer@gmail.com",
      "contact": "91991199199",
      "country": "anywhere"
    },
    "customer2": {
      "name": "name of customer",
      "ageGroup": "20-30",
      "localtion": "customer location",
      "email": "customer@gmail.com",
      "contact": "91991199199",
      "country": "anywhere"
    },
     "customer3": {
      "name": "name of customer",
      "ageGroup": "20-30",
      "localtion": "customer location",
      "email": "customer@gmail.com",
      "contact": "91991199199",
      "country": "anywhere"
    }
  },
   "user2": {
    "customer1": {
      "name": "name of customer",
      "ageGroup": "20-30",
      "localtion": "customer location",
      "email": "customer@gmail.com",
      "contact": "91991199199",
      "country": "anywhere"
    },
    "customer2": {
      "name": "name of customer",
      "ageGroup": "20-30",
      "localtion": "customer location",
      "email": "customer@gmail.com",
      "contact": "91991199199",
      "country": "anywhere"
    },
     "customer3": {
      "name": "name of customer",
      "ageGroup": "20-30",
      "localtion": "customer location",
      "email": "customer@gmail.com",
      "contact": "91991199199",
      "country": "anywhere"
    }
  },
  "user3": {
    "customer1": {
      "name": "name of customer",
      "ageGroup": "20-30",
      "localtion": "customer location",
      "email": "customer@gmail.com",
      "contact": "91991199199",
      "country": "anywhere"
    },
    "customer2": {
      "name": "name of customer",
      "ageGroup": "20-30",
      "localtion": "customer location",
      "email": "customer@gmail.com",
      "contact": "91991199199",
      "country": "anywhere"
    },
     "customer3": {
      "name": "name of customer",
      "ageGroup": "20-30",
      "localtion": "customer location",
      "email": "customer@gmail.com",
      "contact": "91991199199",
      "country": "anywhere"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using the [Attribute pattern](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-attribute-pattern) as you have many similar fields within your objects.

The structure could look like:

```
{
  "user1": {
    "customers": [
      {
        "id": "customer1",
        "name": "name of customer",
        "ageGroup": "20-30",
        "localtion": "customer location",
        "email": "customer@gmail.com",
        "contact": "91991199199",
        "country": "anywhere"
      },
      {
        "id": "customer2",
        "name": "name of customer",
        "ageGroup": "20-30",
        "localtion": "customer location",
        "email": "customer@gmail.com",
        "contact": "91991199199",
        "country": "anywhere"
      }
    ]
  },
  "user2": {
    "customers": [
      {
        "id": "customer1",
        "name": "name of customer",
        "ageGroup": "20-30",
        "localtion": "customer location",
        "email": "customer@gmail.com",
        "contact": "91991199199",
        "country": "anywhere"
      },
      {
        "id": "customer2",
        "name": "name of customer",
        "ageGroup": "20-30",
        "localtion": "customer location",
        "email": "customer@gmail.com",
        "contact": "91991199199",
        "country": "anywhere"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This would allow you to create fewer search indexes for the array of objects like:

```
{ "customers.id": 1, "customers.email": 1}
```

Comment: What if I want to add some more customer for any specific user.

Comment: @MuhammadSaquibShaikh, as your customers is an array of objects, you can now push objects to it using the $push operator https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/